# Print only first matching line of regex and ignore other matches

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to print only the first match of the regex(`foo.*bar.*zoo`) along with rest of the content of the file/variable. Need to ignore all occurrence of this regex, except first.

Here is one scaled down input and some of my attempts to generate the desired results.

### input:

```
 echo "$x"
foo bar zoo
1 2   3
2,4,5
foo bar           zoo
1 9 8
```

### Attempts:

```
echo "$x"|sort -u |uniq
1 2   3
1 9 8
2,4,5
foo bar zoo
foo bar           zoo


echo "$x"|awk '/foo.*bar.*zoo/{if(f==0)print $0;f++}1'
foo bar zoo
foo bar zoo
1 2   3
2,4,5
foo bar           zoo
1 9 8


echo "$x"|grep  -m1 foo
foo bar zoo
```

### Expected result:

```
foo bar zoo
1 2   3
2,4,5
1 9 8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`

```
$ awk '/foo.*bar.*zoo/{if(!c++) print; next} 1' ip.txt
foo bar zoo
1 2   3
2,4,5
1 9 8
```

- `/foo.*bar.*zoo/` if this matches

  - `if(!c++) print` print if `c` is falsey (which is the default for uninitialized variables), next time `c` will be positive number and thus fail this condition
  - `next` skip rest of the commands
- `1` idiomatic way to print contents of `$0` (input record)

Just for fun, some other variations:

```
awk '{if(/foo.*bar.*zoo/) {if(!c++) print} else print}'
awk '!/foo.*bar.*zoo/ || !c++' # RHS will be executed only if LHS fails
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '0,/foo.*bar.*zoo/b;//d' file
```

From the beginning of the file to a regexp that matches your criteria, print as normal.

Thereafter, delete any line that matches the criteria.

Alternative:

```
sed -n '/foo.*bar.*zoo/{p;:a;n;//!p;ba}' file
```

Or:

```
sed '/foo.*bar.*zoo/{x;/./d;g}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

A dirty, quick way to achieve that result is running this:

```
grep -m1 foo filename && grep -v foo filename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/foo.*bar.*zoo/ && c++{next} 1' file
foo bar zoo
1 2   3
2,4,5
1 9 8
```